# Weebly Custom Search Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, textbox

Is it possible to allow for a custom search bar? On one of my webpages, I decided not to use the standard Weebly search bar for design reasons (and plus it wasn't showing up before), and I instead retrofitted a simple text bar onto the navigation bar to be used as the webpage's search bar. Now my question is, how do I give this makeshift search text bar I added to the navigation bar the same functionality as the standard Weebly search bar? If this is possible, can I use the same HTML used in the standard Weebly search bar? I was going to use a third party search bar and embed it into the navigation bar and use that to index my webpage, but it wasn't working the way I wanted it to. I thought of also just moving the standard search bar into the navigation bar using HTML/CSS, but that didn't work correctly either. All I want from this makeshift search bar is it having the ability to navigate to the indexed Weebly search results when the enter button is pressed based on what was entered into the makeshift search bar just like the standard Weebly search bar. Can I do this using HTML?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web design.

Comment: Your easiest option seems Google Custom Search https://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [swiftype](https://swiftype.com/documentation/tutorials/weebly) ? It's a similar search bar as Google custom search bar ! Just try it once before moving on to custom coding which can be done using scripts and the weebly sitemap.xml extension.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can insert both search bar (the Weebly and Google CSE) on your site or specifically on the navigation bar. You can do this using HTML and CSS to position. Just remember Weebly Search Button is for PRO users only but you can still insert it (you can't use). This site of mine might give you some idea: http://www.myweeblytricks.com/2014/07/inserting-search-box-in-weebly.html